# Javascript alert shows up twice

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use a module called disclaimer in Drupal 7 but the Alert "You must enter the year you were born in." Shows up twice and then proceeds to redirect to the URL you are not supposed to see until you verify you are over 18.

I tried the suggestions and it still showed up twice. I think the problem may be the enter button action. Here is the function for that.

```
 Drupal.behaviors.disclaimer = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    // action on enter button
    $('#disclaimer_enter', context).click(function () {
      var check = true;
      // age form is set
      if (settings.disclaimer.ageform == 1) {
        var check = Drupal.checkAge();
      }
      // everything good, add cookie and close colorbox
      if (check) {
        $.cookie(settings.disclaimer.cookie_name, '1', { path: settings.disclaimer.cookie_path });
        $.colorbox.remove();
      }
    });
  },
};
```

}

```
    Drupal.checkAge = function () {
    var now = new Date();
    var date = now.getDate();
    var month = now.getMonth() + 1;
    var year = now.getFullYear();
    var optmonth = jQuery("#edit-disclaimer-age-month option:selected").val();
    var optday = jQuery("#edit-disclaimer-age-day option:selected").val();
    var optyear = jQuery("#edit-disclaimer-age-year option:selected").val();
    var age = year - optyear;
    if (optmonth > month) {age--;} else {if(optmonth == month && optday >= date) {age--;}}
    // if current year, form not set
    if (optyear == year) {
      alert(Drupal.t("You must enter the year you were born in."));
      return alert;
    // if under age, alert and redirect !
    } else if (age < Drupal.settings.disclaimer.limit) {
      alert(Drupal.t("Sorry, you are Under age limit and are prohibited from entering this site!"));
      location.replace(Drupal.settings.disclaimer.exiturl);
      return false;
    } else {
      // age limit ok
      return true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: for starters `return alert;` is probably not what you want to be doing

Answer (score 8):

Because you're **returning alert**. That will show the alert twice and because you aren't returning `false`, will make it continue to the next page.

Try this:

```
if (optyear == year) {
    alert(Drupal.t("You must enter the year you were born in."));
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I tried and it still showed up twice. I added the code above for the Enter button which may be the problem also.

Comment: @user2316905 You'll need to make sure that does `return false` as well then.

Answer (score 1):

The *return alert* is not neccessary.

```
alert(Drupal.t("You must enter the year you were born in."));
//return alert;
```

The alert will be fired by just using alert();

Comment: I tried it and it still showed up twice and redirected to the URL you are supposed to see only if you set your age to over 18.