# Alert() pops up twice in axios interceptor (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, axios, alert

In my Vue app, I instantiate a single instance of axios and use it across the app for HTTP requests. I have set up a response interceptor which checks if any response from the backend is `401 unauthorized`, and if so, shows an alert message. This basic flow has been implemented, but you need to hit "OK" on the alert message twice for it to go away, and I am not sure why.

Axios instance:

```js
import axios, { AxiosError, AxiosInstance, AxiosResponse } from 'axios';

const axiosInstance: AxiosInstance = axios.create();

axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
  (response: AxiosResponse) => response,
  (error: AxiosError) => {
    if(error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
      alert('There has been an issue. Please log out and then log in again.');
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  }
);

export default axiosInstance;
```

The request whose response is being intercepted:

```
import axiosInstance from 'axios-instance';

  public async getloggedInUserId() {
    await axiosInstance.get('/sessions.json')
      .then((response) => {
        if(response.data.user_id) {
          this.SET_USER_ID(response.data.user_id);
        }
      });
  }
```

I've read this thread, but my issue seems to be different: [Javascript alert shows up twice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16199745/11249670)

I've tried changing the return statement from `return Promise.reject(error);` to `return false;` but that did nothing for me.

Comment: Check your browser's _Network_ console

Comment: Can you please check and verify if the `function getloggedInUserId` is not called twice?

Comment: FYI, may or may not be the problem but move your `return Promise.reject(error)` **out** of your `if` (ie, down two lines). With it within, any non 401 HTTP error will be treated as successful

Comment: @Phil Checking the Network console allowed me to pinpoint where exactly the second `alert()` was being called, and removing it solved the issue - thank you!

Comment: If you think your solution could help others, feel free to post your own answer below. Otherwise, you could just close the question

Comment: Done - thanks again (can't accept my own answer yet, will do so later for clarity)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Phil suggested in the comment above, looking at at the **Network** tab in the browser console helped me solve the issue. The console showed how each component in the page was being loaded along with the resulting response code. In short, two processes were actually returning `401`, which was the reason why the `alert` was being called twice.

I have decided to move the code that calls `alert` from a global axios interceptor (called whenever any process returns `401`) to a `.catch` block inside one specific axios process, so that it only gets called once.

Answer (score 0):

Your promise throws error in axios error interceptor, and error called second times.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31108176)